# Retrieve uploaded photo laravel

Tags: php, laravel, upload

So I managed to upload multiple images but now I need to display it in a page I tried something like the code below but it says "unidentified variable: photo"

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/images/{{ $photo->fileName }}" >
```

Here's my upload code, updated my code.

```
    Route::post('space/add', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
  $data = Input::all();

  $provider_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $spaces = Space::where('provider_id', '=', $provider_id)->get();

  $space = new Space;
  ....
  $space->save();


  $file = Input::file('image');
  $provider_email = Auth::user()->email;
  // $space = Space::find($id);
   $rules = array(
                 'file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg'
             );

             $validator = \Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
             if($validator->passes())
             {
               foreach(Input::file('image') as $file)
               {
                  $ext = $file->guessClientExtension(); // (Based on mime type)
                  $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                  $fileName = md5($name) . '.' .$ext;
                  $destinationPath = 'images/' . $provider_email;

                 $file = $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
                 $photo              = new Image;
                 $photo->provider_id = $provider_id;
                 $photo->spaces_id   = $space->id;
                 $photo->filename    = $fileName;
                 $photo->path        = $destinationPath;
                 $photo->save();
                }
              } else{
                  //Does not pass validation
                  $errors = $validator->errors();
              }


  return Redirect::to('user/spaces')->with(array('spaces' => $spaces, 'photo' => $photo));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like

```
return View::make('yourviewname')->with('photo', $photo);
```

this will be in your route or your controller depending on your setup

EDIT:

You will access your varaible in user/spaces through `$photo = Session::get('photo')` from user/spaces you will pass that variable in your `with` i.e. `->with('photo', $photo)`

Comment: Oh yeah haha was calling the wrong thing, anyway so I called like this return Redirect::to('user/spaces')->with('spaces', $spaces); but when I tried the <img src> with the correct variable it says "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$fileName"

Comment: yes, well in your code you have `filename` not `fileName`

Comment: Still getting the same error though, I updated my code above to show the full code of uploading and saving image. I'm trying to display the  uploaded image according to the space.

Comment: post the content of `user/spaces`

Comment: Route::get('user/spaces', function()
{
  $title = "Manage Spaces";
  $provider_id = Auth::user()->id;
  $spaces = Space::where('provider_id', '=', $provider_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'id')->get();
  // $id = Space::find($id);
  return View::make('spaces.spaces')->with('spaces', $spaces)->with('title', $title);
});

That's what I have for user/spaces

Comment: Okay was trying to display the image in user/spaces, sorry I didn't quite get your edit.